# equation to create unique value

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, hash-function

I have a  list of n objects

```
say [ apple, orange, carrot, cherry, banana ]
```

Now I am trying to come up with an equation which will generate an unique number for each combinations from this list.

eg :

say I assign following values for each items

```
apple = 1
orange = 2
carrot = 3
cherry = 4
banana = 5
```

If I directly add the individual values to generate combination score then the values will be

```
apple      = 1
apple, carrot = 4
apple, orange = 3
```

But here multiple combination can have same scores.

I need to generate an equation which will generate UNIQUE score for all of these combination.

POSITION IS NOT AN ISSUE.

Score(apple,orange,carrot) = Score(carrot, apple, orange) = Score (orange, apple, carrot)

But Score (apple, carrot) $\ne$ Score(cherry)

How this can be generated ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: Why not just combine them into a single number, e.g. apple, orange and carrot ($1$ and $2$ and $3$) becomes $123$. Or, mathematically, multiply each number with $10^i$, with $i$ their position, starting count at $0$.

Comment: Eric, then apple, orange and carrot (1 and 2 and 3) = 123 and  orange, apple and carrot (2 and 1 and 3) = 213 are not equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a prime number to each object.

Let the score for each combination be the product of the prime numbers assigned to the objects in the combination.

This will also allow you to use the score to record multiple occurrences of items (if you want).

Every such score created can be uniquely factorised to identify the items in your list.

Comment: Yes this works, thank you. Is there a better way if the number of objects in list > 10000. Because then the product will be so huge.

Comment: That's because the number of different combinations is so large!

Comment: yes but still can this value  be reduced some how ?

Comment: How many objects are there likely to be in a typical "combination"? Do certain objects appear more frequently? Are there some pairings that appear more frequently than others? Are there some prohibited pairings?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it sounds as if all you want is to assign each element a unique exponentiation of a base value; for example,

- apple = 1 i.e. $2^0$
- banana = 2 i.e. $2^1$
- cherry = 4 i.e. $2^2$

etc.
Then any way you add them, you can always decompose the sum. More simply:

- apple = 1
- banana = 10
- cherry = 100

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.